# Getting a Report Viewer to fill a grid?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to use WPF to present a report to the user. I went ahead and used the report wizard to create the chart that I wanted. My issue is that I cannot seem to get the actual chart to fill the `Grid`/`WindowsFormsHost` that it is nested in.

It seems to want to stay at whatever width and height that I stretched it to in the RDLC designer. Is there any way to set it to fill its parent when I initialize it?

Edit:

Heres my XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="CloudMonitor.Client.UI.Start"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="Start" Height="972" Width="1315"
xmlns:convert="clr-namespace:CloudMonitor.Client.Convert"
xmlns:rv="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms;assembly=Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms" >
    <Window.Resources>
    <convert:ConnectionStatusConverter x:Key="ConnectionStatusConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height=".9*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height=".1*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid x:Name="ReportGrid" Grid.Row="0">
            <WindowsFormsHost >
                <rv:ReportViewer x:Name="_reportViewer"/>
            </WindowsFormsHost>
        </Grid>

        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button x:Name="InitializeHubButton" Grid.Column="0" Content="Init Hub" Width="50" Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Click="InitializeHubButton_OnClick"></Button>
            <Button x:Name="SendSimpleHailButton" Grid.Column="1" Content="Simple Hail" Width="90" Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Command="{Binding SendTestHail}" ></Button>
        </Grid>

        <Rectangle Fill="{Binding IsConnected, Converter={StaticResource ConnectionStatusConverter}}" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="right" Height="20" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="20"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Have you set the Height or width fixed? please show your XAML. I suspect that you change runtime size instead of design size

Comment: @ericpap I added my XAML to my post.

Comment: That's just an extract of the XAML. The problema should be elsewhere. Can you post the complete XAML? are you using a usercontrol or a window?

Comment: @ericpap I added the rest of my XAML. I am currently using a window.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a Usercontrol and put the Report Viewer there then set it to your Grid.

Answer (score 0):

Try replace this line from Window Definition:

```
Title="Start" Height="972" Width="1315"
```

With this:

```
Title="Start" d:DesignHeight="972" d:DesignWidth="1315"
```